# Is there a PayPal IPN when a suspended subscription is reactivated?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

When a paypal recurring payment is suspend an IPN with either one of the following `txn_type` will be sent

```
recurring_payment_suspended
recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment
```

Question: Is there an IPN to notify of a re-activation, like:

```
recurring_payment_reactivated
```

I could not find any info on SO, Google and https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables

Or does anyone know why PayPal would provide an IPN to tell us when a recurring payment is suspended
but not when its re-activated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested this scenario on the sandbox.  I created a new profile using `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` and I immediately got the `recurring_payment_profile_created` IPN as expected.

I then suspended the profile using `ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus` and immediately got the `recurring_payment_suspended` IPN as expected.

I then reactivated the profile using `ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus`, but I did NOT get any new IPN from this action.

Based on those findings I would say, no, you will not get one in production either.

That said, I always recommend using the `GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails` API to check the current status of a profile any time users log in to a paid area of your site (or attempt to access anything that requires a valid profile.)

Comment: i tested on production it yield the same results as your sandbox test. sandbox is at times inconsistent with their production system tho'. there an ipn to inform about suspension then it would be logical to have one that reverses the suspension, apparently not. oh well. and thanks for your suggestion i will go with that.